# Internet Explorer (all versions) not applying media query on only two random elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have two elements/classes in a `@media screen` query that exclusively Internet Explorer isn't recognizing. Every other element/class under that `@media screen` query is being recognized perfectly fine by IE. I've been scratching my head and can't seem to understand why.

Obligatory cache has been refreshed.

**HTML**

```
<span id="follow-76">
   <span data-userid="76" class="icon-user-follow" title="Follow" onclick="follow_user(76)">
   </span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {

    .icon-user-follow, .icon-user-followed {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 1px 5px 3px;
      border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius:50px;
      -moz-border-radius:50px;
      top: 18px;
      left: initial;
      right: 25px;
    }

    .icon-user-follow {
      border-color:#69bc63
    }

    .icon-user-followed {
      border-color:#555B67
    }
}
```

Comment: How far back in IE are you going? only IE9+ supports media queries. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Comment: @Delto can you show us the complete css stylesheet. There possibly could be an overriding problem.

Comment: @MarounBaydoun I figured it out, will post the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, and for future reference here is the answer.

Internet Explorer doesn't recognize `left: initial;`. I had to change it to `left: auto;` and all worked as intended.

Hope this helps anyone else facing this problem in the future.